# Allure xml files created with steps. Index.html inside site folder is empty - Allure Maven TestNG

Tags: maven, testng, allure

I tried command `mvn clean test site` command to generate allure report. `xml file` inside `allure-results` folder is created properly with all steps. Howvever, `index.html` file inside `site -> allure-maven-plugin` folder is empty. There are no test case results displayed in Overview or any other sections available in Allure report. I am using `Selenium WebDriver` with `Arquillian` and `TestNG`.

Please find my POM file below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ABC</groupId>
  <artifactId>XYZ</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <version.org.jboss.arquillian>1.1.12.Final</version.org.jboss.arquillian>
      <version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone>2.1.0.Alpha1</version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone>
      <version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene>2.1.0.Final</version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene>
      <version.screenshooter>2.1.0.Final</version.screenshooter>
      <version.javax.mail>1.5.6</version.javax.mail>
      <jackson.version>2.7.0</jackson.version>
      <aspectj.version>1.8.3</aspectj.version>
      <allure.version>1.4.11</allure.version>
      <version.maven.surefire>2.19.1</version.maven.surefire>
   </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.11</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.testng</groupId>
         <artifactId>arquillian-testng-standalone</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>  
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
         <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
         <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.graphene}</version>
         <type>pom</type>
         <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-browser-screenshooter</artifactId>
        <version>${version.screenshooter}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsurfer</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsurfer-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>${version.javax.mail}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <!-- Arquillian Core dependencies -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
         <!-- Arquillian Drone dependencies and WebDriver/Selenium dependencies -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.maven.surefire}</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
                 <suiteXmlFiles>
                     <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                  </suiteXmlFiles>
                  <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                    </property>
                  </properties>
            </configuration>   
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
   <reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-reports/</outputDirectory>
                    <allureResultsDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</allureResultsDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above pom.xml works fine. Looks like default browser to view the report is Firefox. When opened in IE and chrome, index.html is shown empty.  Results are displayed in firefox browser. Need to find the way to change this default configuration.